# How to get the correct suggestion for the wrong searched term in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am quite new to ElasticSearch and it has been very nice getting to know about it. I have to implement something as the image attached below suggests. How do I hit this? I tried looking for it but did not get anything close to it. SO had to post it as a new question.

Does ES have to do anything with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Suggesters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html)

"The suggest feature suggests similar looking terms based on a provided text by using a suggester. Parts of the suggest feature are still under development."

Answer (score 0):

you can use this：http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html

using term suggest,it can fix you wrong word from it's dictionary.